# Create a separate code writing service

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

We have all seen people come and ask questions where all they want is someone to write the solution to their problem. Perhaps they can't do it or, more likely, they have a time-sensitive project due and need the product now.

This is *not* a code writing service and therefore many of these are downvoted and closed.

However, many people are happy to provide this service. Could we allow this in a different site? Perhaps stackservice.com. Then members that want to assist can, and perhaps they can be paid. With remuneration perhaps locked to users with a high reputation, or rates increasing with reputation.

Thoughts?

Comment: There are plenty of sites where you can hire a freelance programmer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is already deviating enough from its core Q&A business as it is. I don't see why they should enter yet another market, especially one that is adequately served by existing solutions.

Comment: For such a thing *without* payment involved: http://area51.stackexchange.com, good luck. For anything involving payment: oh god, such a quagmire…

Comment: There's already a SO site for hiring people: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Answer (score 36):

This is probably never going to happen within this network: it's too contrary to its core values.

Based on previous discussions, the typical main Meta arguments against this are going to be:

- A code writing site would never manage to build a healthy ecosystem in which experts would want to spend time. There's nothing to learn for them there; just do what they probably already do at work, write code others ask them to write. As a result, there would never be enough *knowledgeable* users - and those are needed for quality control to take place (through quality answers, voting, and comments). The place would become a dumpster fire in no time. Communities are ecosystems just like natural ones: if you get just one component wrong (like the acidity of your soil, the makeup of your water, wrong temperature), essential organisms won't develop and the system will fail. This idea is definitely such a case.
- Adding a monetary incentive would lead to an unhealthy culture of competitiveness incompatible with the current system, which is based on virtual, imaginary rewards (reputation points). When you have a *financial* interest in seeing others lose so you win - in low-income countries, this kind of activity could actually be a serious source of income - problems with fraud (already prevalent on SO as it is!) will become *really* serious. This would likely destroy any sense of community.
- Adding a monetary incentive will greatly reduce the social prestige and intrinsic value of participating. When you contribute for free, you're volunteering, making you feel good about yourself, others respect you, and it's something you may be able to put on your resumé. When you contribute for money (even if it's just a ridiculous $.50 for an hour's work), those positive aspects go away.
- Paying out money could actually be a negative for user motivation: the amounts shelled out would likely be minuscule compared to a programmer's salary or hourly rate. This would make answering questions on such a site completely unattractive to many of those knowledgeable people whose input you need.
- A code writing site would not contribute much to the network's mission, to build resources that are useful for many future visitors, not only the asker themselves.

Anyone is free to build this kind of service, though - and some already are. (I think I read about two startups the other day that want to do exactly this, but I can't remember their names.)